# Find the natural parameter space of an exponential family with $h=e^{-x^2}$

Tags: exponential-distribution

Determine the natural parameter space of the exponential family of distribution of dimension one with $\chi=1, T=x,h=e^{-x^2}$. And $h(x)=e^{-|x|}$.

**Work**:

The natural parameter space is the set of $\theta$ such that the integral in $A(\theta)=log\int h(x)e^{\theta T(x) }dx$ is finite. Here,

$$\begin{split}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)e^{\theta T(x)}&=\int e^{-x^2}e^{\theta x}dx\\
&=\int e^{-x^2+\theta x}dx\end{split}$$

which I do not know how to integrate. Is this...right?

Comment: $-x^2 + \theta x = -\left(x - \frac \theta 2\right)^2 + \frac {\theta^2}4$

Comment: But how is "$h = e^{-x^2}$" *and* "$h(x) = e^{-|x|}$" at the same time? Are you abusing notation by having $h$ mean two things? Are are you mixing up two problems?

Comment: Ah, thanks. lol that’s another part, to do it with another h(x). Should’ve put “part b”